# Can coiling a bandsaw blade permanently twist it?

Tags: band-saw

I bought a used 10 inch bandsaw and it came with several blades.  All the spare blades came coiled.  I just put on the 1/4 inch one and it has a twist in it.  Looking at some howtos, coiling a blade involves some twisting of the blade.  Can you create a permanent twist by coiling, perhaps by not doing it correctly?  (The answer will determine how I store the blades).

Comment: Can it? Possibly, however, storing them coiled is a long standing tradition. It's also how they're packaged for shipment by the manufacturer. I doubt they're intentionally damaging brand new products.

Comment: I think being doubtful about coiling being an issue, in general, is the right call given that it's both longstanding practice *and* still done by the manufacturers themselves (with no instruction to uncoil ASAP when the blade gets into the shop). Plus of course nearly every bandsaw user coils blades that aren't in use. *"...perhaps by not doing it correctly?"* This may be the heart of the Q, because I'm sure the answer is yes.... doing a lot of things *incorrectly* can lead to problems. I don't think there's any reason to think this would be an exception to that :-)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Good blades are kinda pricey, and I'm a newbie, so if there's a chance I'll ruin them by coiling them wrong, I'll find another way to store them.

Answer (score 1):

Can you damage them?  Yes if you put the twist in or unwrap them incorrectly.  However, correctly folding them and unfolding them will not damage or twist them.  I have a bandsaw mill that has the same kind of blades and we store all of them that way.  Take care and you won't damage them, and taking care you won't damage yourself either.